# How to change the color and size of tag_levels in patchwork

Tags: r

we want to change the color and size of tag using patchwork, but no changes occur

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(gear)) + facet_wrap(~cyl)
# Add title, etc. to a patchwork
p1 + p2 + plot_annotation('This is a title', caption = 'made with patchwork')
# Change styling of patchwork elements
p1 + p2 +
  plot_annotation(
    title = 'This is a title',
    caption = 'made with patchwork',
    theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16,color="red"))
  )
# Add tags to plots
p1 / (p2 | p3) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A',theme = theme(plot.tag = element_text(color = "red")))
```

Answer (score 5):

With the '&' synthax describe in the website it seems to work well.

```
p1 / (p2 | p3) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A') &
  theme(plot.tag = element_text(color = "red"))
```

[image]